# What is the correct way of writing a single byte of data into a binary file using PHP?

Tags: php

When I write a string, PHP writes 4 bytes into the file. How do I write a single byte?

Thanks

Comment: Show some code to demonstrate what you mean. $fp = fopen('data.txt', 'w'); fwrite($fp, '1'); fclose($fp); will write a single byte (ASCII '1') to the file.

Comment: Using fopen(), fwrite(), fclose() and checking with `stat`, I get a 1 byte file ... Please post more information on how you're writing to the file ... And how do you check the file size?

Comment: Use `var_dump($string)` to see what's in it and how big it is. There could be hidden control characters like newlines/carriage returns (\n\r) hiding in there. Or you're on a UTF-16 system of some sort and wrote out two characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the handle in binary mode

```
foo@bar: /tmp/test > cat test.php 
<?php
 $fp = fopen('test.bin', 'w+b');
 fwrite($fp, 'a');
 fclose($fp);

foo@bar: /tmp/test > php test.php 
foo@bar: /tmp/test > ls -lh test.bin 
-rw-r--r--  1 foo  wheel     1B Mar 24 14:40 test.bin
```

just add b to the end of your fopen mode.

Comment: From http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php : *"As of PHP 4.3.2, the default mode is set to binary for all platforms that distinguish between binary and text mode."* ... So as I read this it won't matter that much ... Also, the "worst case" is that the string written will be "a\r\n", which is 3 bytes, not 4 ...